# How to automate the testing of a device with mechanical switches?

Tags: testing, automation, components, end-to-end, hardware-interface

we need to do some automated end to end testing of our component chain, which consists of a number of windows services that talk to each other - these are easily tested (and we do it today), however at one end of the chain is some hardware, that is controlled by a human who presses various buttons that makes the software inside 'talk' to the rest of our component chain.

how can we automate the the button pressing? are there special m/c's that do that sort of thing?

does anyone do this sort of thing and how?

Many thanks.

Comment: Digital I/O interface. Relay contacts in parallel with the switches.  I do this with keypads for test purposes.  The tests run OK, but the rattling noise is annoying.

Comment: Oh - hang on - wrong site.  This is off-topic for SO.  Try the electronics/hardware sites!